# How to connect to local TCP WebSocket via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rust, tcp, tcplistener

I have a database that I am hosting locally and need to be able to access it using Javascript for this website that I have https://nujabes.xyz/.  For the server side of things, I am hosting it using Rust because that is what my database is written in:

TCP Server `Rust`:

```rust
use std::{
    io::Read,
    net::{Shutdown::Both, TcpListener, TcpStream},
    thread::spawn,
};

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut data = [0 as u8; 50]; // using 50 byte buffer
    while match stream.read(&mut data) {
        Ok(_size) => {
            //println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(data[0..size].to_vec()));

            // stream.write(&data[0..size]).unwrap();
            true
        }
        Err(_) => {
            println!(
                "An error occurred, terminating connection with {}",
                stream.peer_addr().unwrap()
            );
            stream.shutdown(Both).unwrap();
            false
        }
    } {}
}

fn main() {
    let address = "localhost";
    let port = "80";

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(format!("{}:{}", address, port)).unwrap();
    println!("{}", format!("Server listening on port {}", port));
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                println!("New connection: {}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
                spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream);
                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }
    // close the socket server
    drop(listener);
}
```

Client Side `Javascript`:

```js
function connect() {
    let address = "localhost";
    let port = "80";

    console.log(`Attempting to connect to ${address} at ${port}...`);
    let socket = new WebSocket(`wss://${address}:${port}`);

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(`Message :: ${event.data}`)
    };

    socket.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log(`Closed :: ${event.code} :: ${event.reason}`);
    };

    socket.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log(`Error :: ${error.message}`)
    };
}
```

The output from the console after pressing the `Login` or `Register` button on the main page to cause it to attempt the connection is of the following:

```
Attempting to connect to localhost at 80... main.js:8:13
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:80/. main.js:9:17
Error :: undefined main.js:20:17
Closed :: 1006 ::
```

There is also feedback on the server's side where it is actually recieving a connection:

```
Server listening on port 80
New connection: [::1]:64374
```

Why isn't the connection holding?  What is up with this Firefox error?

Context:  I have forwarded port `80` as well as a few other ports already.

Comment: As said in the answer, WebSocket is more than TCP socket (and this is not specific to Rust). [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) explains very well what happens *under the hood*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your server is trying to use regular TCP sockets while your client-side code is using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), which do make use of TCP sockets but layer a whole new protocol on top of that.

The connection does get established, but during the client-side's WebSocket handshake etc, it fails and therefore errors.

You're better off finding a Rust library that allows you to create a WebSocket server instead of a regular socket server. I don't think client-side JavaScript can even use regular sockets.